# How to save a register with a dired buffer?

Tags: dired, registers

I'm new to Emacs. I saw that you could have registers with special files.
I really like that feature, and I was wondering if I could get the same functionality with a Dired buffer.
For example, the following works:

```lisp
    (set-register ?e (cons 'file "~/.emacs.d/init.el"))
```

And I would like to something along the lines of:

```lisp
    (set-register ?o '(buffer '(dired "path/somewhere")))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
switch-to-buffer: Wrong type argument: stringp, ('(dired "path/somewhere")).
```

How could I get that functionality to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you have to use the "file" command and simply specify a directory. It will open dired outomatically.

As in:

```
(set-register ?o (cons 'file "path/to/directory"))
```

`C-h v register-alist` tells you all the possibilities for register values:

```
Alist of elements (NAME . CONTENTS), one for each Emacs register.
NAME is a character (a number).  CONTENTS is a string, number, marker, list
or a struct returned by ‘registerv-make’.
A list of strings represents a rectangle.
A list of the form (file . FILE-NAME) represents the file named FILE-NAME.
A list of the form (file-query FILE-NAME POSITION) represents
 position POSITION in the file named FILE-NAME, but query before
 visiting it.
A list of the form (buffer . BUFFER-NAME) represents the buffer BUFFER-NAME.
A list of the form (WINDOW-CONFIGURATION POSITION)
 represents a saved window configuration plus a saved value of point.
A list of the form (FRAME-CONFIGURATION POSITION)
 represents a saved frame configuration (a.k.a. "frameset") plus
 a saved value of point.
```

Comment: Posting the answer you discovered yourself -- very nice! You should mark it accepted too, as a little reward for yourself.

Comment: Hi @PhilHudson! Thanks for the reminder. Stackexchange only told me to wait 2 days before marking my own answer as correct. Have a good day ^_^.